# How to remove the language switch icon from Windows form using c# in WinCE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

[image]

Hi,

I am currently developing an application for Wince 6.0 using C#(.net compact framework 3.5). The language switch icon keeps on popping up in my form.

Is there a way to switch it off in Windows or in my script?Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity what is the manufacturer and model of the device you are using. Because Wince is such a customization platform, OEM's sometimes throw in some custom features that mess with applications.

Comment: Actually I am working in a company producing our own device, but by the sound of it, there is a way to configure the Wince not to have this?